# Delete cookies in WebDriverJS

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can I delete cookies in WebDriverJS? I want to run some tests on a website that creates login cookies (and I have to clear cookies each time I want to run the tests).

I want to start a clean session each time I run the test. What can I do?

Comment: Are you facing any problem in using `deleteAllCookies()` method?

Comment: I tried to use driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); but that's a Java method. I'm using WebdriverJS

Comment: As seen from the example given under EXAMPLE section in this link `https://github.com/dmachi/webdriver-js` , we can use `session.deleteAllCookies();`

Comment: in [webdriverio](http://webdriver.io) it is `client.deleteCookie()`, it removes all cookies

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm that `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()` works in WebDriverJS.

If you view the source and search for `deleteAllCookies` you'll see the function.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#1014